# How can i manage the visual elements via CSOM?

Tags: list, javascript, csom, jsom

There is a button in my Homepage which I created with HTML, CSS & JavaScript. I am using CSOM to reach the list. When a user click on the button, should I make CSOM code work. How could I implement them together?

Comment: by CSOM do you mean C# code or Javascript?

Comment: I mean C sharp.

Comment: I think  you should update question with more information, like what code is it how have you deployed it is it a Solution WSP what environment are you using SPO or SP on-premise